# Calculate price variation following a threshold in R

Tags: r

I have a following time-series price data:

```
18/01/2008  7.4811
22/01/2008  7.5267
31/01/2008  7.8289
01/02/2008  7.82
...
30/10/2008  7.81
31/10/2008  7.75
```

I build a function `calVariation` to calculate the variation of prize as: `variation = log(data/data[1,1])`.

- `calVariation` starts from `Line 1` of the data, i.e., calculate variations for `data[1:nrow(data),]`, then find in the `variation` result array the first value that is less than a threshold of `5%`.
- If nothing found, the function `calVariation` should run again but start from the next line of the data, i.e., compute variations for `data[2:nrow(data),]`
- If it finds that the variation at line `n` is less than threshold `5%`, it will save the column of the original data from `Line 1` to `Line n` to one column of a matrix `mat`. Now the original data will be reduced to `data[n:nrow(data),]` and become the input for `calVariation` to calculate in the next step.

Following is my code.

```
pathway <- 'C:/'
decimal <- ","
threshold <- -0.05
database <- as.matrix(read.csv(paste(pathway,"Data_origin.csv",sep=""), header = FALSE, sep = ";", dec = decimal))

data_p <- as.matrix(database[,2])
data_p <- as.matrix(as.numeric(data_p))
rownames(data_p) <- database[,1]

calVariation <- function(mData, threshold){ 
  if(nrow(mData) > 1) {  
    vari <- log(mData/mData[1,1])

    if (any(vari < threshold) == FALSE) { # Not found any value < -5
      mData <- as.matrix(mData[2:nrow(mData),])
      mData <- calVariation(mData, threshold)
    }

    else { # Found value < -5
      threshold_id <- min(which(vari < threshold))
      mData <- as.matrix(mData[1:threshold_id, ])
    }
  } else (
    mData <- NULL
  ) 

  return(mData)
}


data <- data_p
mat <- NULL
rowid <- 0

while (nrow(data) > 1 && is.null(data) == FALSE) {
  temp <- matrix(NA, nrow(data_p), 2)
  data <- calVariation(data, threshold)

  if (is.null(data) == FALSE) {
    temp[1:nrow(data), 1] <- rownames(data) 
    temp[1:nrow(data), 2] <- data 
    rowid <- rowid + nrow(data)     
    mat <- cbind(mat, temp)
    data <- as.matrix(data_p[rowid:nrow(data_p),])    
  } else {
    break()
  }

}
```

It returns this error: `Error in if (any(vari < threshold) == FALSE) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. I guess that when `vari` becomes `NA` this error happens but I tried to use something like `is.na` function to get rid of this but it didn't work out.

The original data for the test can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdykistsqos2biv/Data_origin.csv?dl=0). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()` so others can help. See more here: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is in the while block

```
Error in if (any(vari < threshold) == FALSE) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE  needed\n"
Error in data_p[rowid:nrow(data_p), ] : subscript out of bounds
```

One suggestion in future when diagnosing hard to debug errors, use tryCatch, rewritten calVariation()

```
calVariation <- function(mData, threshold){ 


tryCatch( {if(nrow(mData) > 1) {  
vari <- log(mData/mData[1,1])


if ( any(vari < threshold) == FALSE) { # Not found any value < -5
  mData <- as.matrix(mData[2:nrow(mData),])
  mData <- calVariation(mData, threshold)
}

else { # Found value < -5
  threshold_id <- min(which(vari < threshold))
  mData <- as.matrix(mData[1:threshold_id, ])
}
} else {
mData <- NULL
} },error = function(err) {

# print the error
print(paste("error:  ",err))

} )
  return(mData)
}
```